# Production security for .json private keys in Google Cloud Platform and FireBase

Tags: firebase, security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, credentials

We're developing a full-stack platform deployed on GCP via AppEngine and with Firebase (Firestore + RealTimeDb) as noSql Db Module.

We're going live but I've a doubt. Now we're using the Firebase `private-key.json` to interface our software to Firebase and it is saved to a folder in the project like `src/firebase` and it is bound to our code through:

```html
admin.credential.cert(require(path))
```

The API key and the path are saved to the `.env` file.

We're using the same technique to use the GCP client libraries (for example like Logging system).
I've also see that for GCP client libraries Google advises to use environment variables, but also indicates that they're active only during the session.

Anyway, to respect and to optimize security of our system: we should go live with these configurations or we have to change them? Please, do you have any advice to not expose the credentials and to don't have a vulnerable system?

Thanks guys

Comment: You are mixing two very different services (App Engine and Firebase). App Engine does not require a service-account.json file. Use ADC (Application Default Credentials). 2) Deploying a service-accout.json file inside your application source code is NOT SECURE.

Comment: Hi John, thanks! I  have a Node.js Backend where i'm using Google Cloud Client Libraries and Firebase. This backend is deployed on AppEngine. So, is there a distinction between GCP config key and Firebase config key, or i'm going wrong ?

Comment: App Engine and Firebase are different services. Yes, there is a difference between their configuration files.

Comment: Ok perfect. So, how can i configure them in production deploy?

Comment: Do you really need the API Key and the firebase private key in your nodeJS backend? From my understanding, if the AppEngine service has the permission to use Firebase product (Firestore, Firebase function maybe,...) it's enough, correct?

Comment: As I understand, AppEngine "runs" under some service account. It may be possible to grant relevant IAM roles to that account (i.e. `roles/datastore.user`), so it can work with the Firestore service. If you would like - you can keep them in different projects... Thus, I am not sure why json private key files are required first time, unless I completely misunderstood the issue.

Comment: [This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers#node.js) could be useful for best practices in the scenario you describe. Are you following the practices outlined here?

Comment: Thank you guys! Anyway: yes, we have node.js running on GCP with the necessities to use Firestore, Real-time db and Google Logging Client library too.

Comment: For Google Logging we've used the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, saving the .json keyfile in the cloud system. We have to do this with firestore too? How can we use both the services with an unique variable? Now firestore is initialized with firebase and admin js modules, calling the initializeApp method.

Comment: Looks good. As John said, they are different services each with their own connectivity method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting John Hanley's, guillaume blaquiere's, al-dann's and Alex L's comments as a Community Wiki for visibility.

App Engine and Firebase are different services. There is a difference between their configuration files.

App Engine does not require a `service-account.json` file. Use Application Default Credentials (ADC).
Deploying a `service-accout.json` file inside your application source code is NOT SECURE.

The AppEngine service has the permission to use Firebase product (Firestore, Firebase functions) which should be sufficient. This means that you don't really need an API Key and a Firebase private key in your Node.js back-end.

App Engine runs under a service account. It may be possible to grant relevant IAM roles to that account (i.e. `roles/datastore.user`), so it can work with the Firestore service. If you would like - you can keep them in different projects.

You can refer to the [Node.js quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers#node.js) for guidance in this scenario.